# Use PyWin32 to create windows service, but it can't create file in %LOCALAPPDATA%

Tags: python, windows, windows-services, pywin32

I have built a windows service application by pywin32. And I can't create any files or directories in the directory '%LOCALAPPDATA%'. I think the reason leading to this problem maybe my app do not have enough privilege to create file, but I'm not quite sure about it. I am a beginner on Windows programming. How can I solve this problem?

Here is my code:

```
import traceback
import os
import sys

import win32serviceutil
import win32security
import win32api
import win32service
import win32event
import win32file

class newsLauncher(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):

    _svc_name_ = 'Test_service'
    _svc_display_name_ = 'Test for service'


    def __init__(self, *args):
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self, *args)
        self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None, 0, 0, None)


    def log(self, msg):
        import servicemanager
        servicemanager.LogInfoMsg(str(msg))
        def sleep(self, sec):
            win32api.Sleep(sec*1000, True)


    def SvcDoRun(self):
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_START_PENDING)
        try:
            cwd = os.path.join(os.environ['LOCALAPPDATA'], "test_service")
            os.mkdir(cwd)
            os.chdir(cwd)

            open("test.log", 'w').write("success create file.")

            self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_RUNNING)

            win32event.WaitForSingleObject(self.hWaitStop, win32event.INFINITE)
            self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOPPED)
        except Exception as e:
            self.log('Exception: %s' % e)
            self.log('line %d' % traceback.tb_lineno(sys.exc_info()[2]))
            self.SvcStop()
            self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOPPED)


    def SvcStop(self):
        self.log("in stop")

        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)

        win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)
        self.log("stoped")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(newsLauncher)
```

Comment: Probably has to do with the logon used for the service. See this Microsoft resource: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677948(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I'd hazard a guess that the environment variable LOCALAPPDATA isn't actually set for a service.  Does Python not provide a way to retrieve the path for a known folder?  (In C you would use SHGetKnownFolderPath.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston In fact Windows Service run as a system account named 'LocalSystem', so the environment variable LOCALAPPDATA here is 'C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local'. That's why I guess the app do not have enough privilege.

Comment: @stark print? I haven't do any print. The app run without any exception or output, and there's no file created in 'LOCALAPPDATA'.

Comment: Unless you've messed with the permissions on that folder, or have configured the service to use a restricted SID (which you can check using `sc qsidtype`), you have enough privilege to write to the folder.

Comment: @HarryJohnston I checked it. The permissions on that folder is OK, but the service's SERVICE_SID_TYPE is 'None'. Is it the reason I can't create file?

Comment: I find something new here. In fact, I successfully created the file， and successfully read/write data from it. But it does not exist in the path 'C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local' which was the value of 'LOCALAPPDATA'. I don't know where it is. Is that something called 'data redirection'? I was confused.

Comment: @Yyao Why do you think that it is even trying to create a file?  If you don't have a file or a print or an error, why do you think this code even ran?

Comment: Thank you very much. I think I've solved this problem. The real reason is I use a 32-bit python interpreter. So OS run my service on [WoW64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WoW64). Although the value of 'LOCALAPPDATA' is displayed as 'C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local', the system redirect it to 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local'. And all my file was created in there.

Comment: @stark ...I'm wrong...I should be aware of the problem at very beginning. If I do that, I will save a lot of time. I think I still need more practice. Thank you for reminding me.